# Pass by value or reference, sorting array of objects recursively

Tags: php, arrays, recursion

I'm somewhat of a PHP newbie, only doing this as a hobby for the last couple of years.

I have an object of this prototype:

```
menu_node ->name
          ->order
          ->children
```

where `children` may be an array of these same objects - so could go many levels deep.  I wrote a simple recursive function that goes through the nesting and executes `usort` on each `->children`:

```
private function sort_node( $node ) {
    if ( isset($node->children) ) {
        usort(  $node->children,
                function($a, $b) {return ($a->order == $b->order) ? 0 : ( ($a->order < $b->order) ? -1 : 1 );}
        );
        foreach ( $node->children as $child_node ) {
            $this->sort_node( $child_node );
        }
    }
    return $node;
}
```

It seems to work fine.  But I'm not sure "why" it works fine, which I don't like - I want to know for sure.

I'm worried about what goes on with the passed-in object inside of that `foreach` loop - am I consistently modifying the memory space of the passed-in object or am I just lucky that my version and configuration of PHP happens to work ok, but it's really indeterminate as to how it would work across other installations?

I guess I am not sure when to use the argument format `&$node` instead of `$node`?  Same for the iterator variable `$child_node`, in that loop.

Any insight or confirmation that what I have here is ok, would be appreciated.

Comment: If I understand you right, using &$node just means you don't need to use 'return $node' as you are changing the original object not a copy of it. In other words, it works fine at present, because each time you call sort_node, you pass in a copy of $node which is processed, and then that copy is returned. So you're not messing with the original object at any point. When you recurse, another copy is made of that $child_node, and so on. I don't think there's anything here that wouldn't be portable across any machine that runs vanilla PHP5.

Comment: @fred2 -- ah, ok that makes sense; so PHP default is to do a deep copy of any objects passed as arg to a function?  The foreach still confuses me however...I am not sure why the iterator variable is modifying the original object (I thought I read somewhere that you can't rely on this).

Comment: Yeah - that's why there's a limit on recursion depth in PHP by default - so you don't get some sort of endless loop that ends up filling your memory.

Comment: I presume it's because usort works on the array passed in (equivalent to using &). That said, it's not the behaviour I would have expected either, as $node is a copy each time. So I understand your confusion.  Is there some other passing by reference going on in the code?

Comment: No, the initial call to sort_node is with a $menu_node object.  I almost feel like I have to set the iterator variable in the foreach as **&$child_node**, to force it to be a reference and not work on a copy of the array...but that leads me right back to "why is it working correctly now?"

Comment: Could be this (from php.net) - have to admit I was unaware: "Since PHP 5, new returns a reference automatically, so using =& in this context is deprecated and produces an E_DEPRECATED message in PHP 5.3 and later, and an E_STRICT message in earlier versions. As of PHP 7.0 it is syntactically invalid. (Technically, the difference is that, in PHP 5, object variables, much like resources, are a mere pointer to the actual object data, so these object references are not "references" in the same sense used before (aliases). For more information, see Objects and references.)"

Comment: Interesting.  I do create the initial $menu_node with "(object) new StdClass" -- so maybe *that* is setting "is a reference" to true - and causes the foreach to say "ok, I need to use the reference, not make a copy of this"?  I am just guessing here.  I did change the foreach iterator to **&$child_node** -- and it still works fine.  Maybe I should look at E_STRICT to see what it says...